# How to run a script in Idle shell when double-clicked in Window OS?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, shell, python-idle

**Summary:**

Windows User, that has python installed on his/her machine, double-clicks a (.py) or (.bat) file and it launches `myapp.py` in the *Python Idle Shell*.

Alternatively, the `myapp.py` is able to launch itself in *Python Idle Shell* after getting double clicked but that is probably not feasible.

**More rambly (to prevent misunderstanding):**

If someone wants to run a (.py) file via *Python Idle Shell*, they would right-click on the file > 'Edit with IDLE' > 'Run Module (F5)'. How can I run the (.py) file via *Python Idle Shell* with just double-clicking a (.py) file or (.bat) file?

**Additional info**

OS: Windows 7 (x64)

Python: 2.7

Comment: The IDLE shell would not be able to be used without modification (to my knowledge). You could make a .bat file with `python myapp.py` but it wouldn't use IDLE.

Comment: You could make a batch file that started `idle` and used it's `-r` command-line option to run the .py file. Here's the documentation on Idle's [Command line usage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html#command-line-usage).

Comment: @martineau You just answered my question. Do you want to post this as an answer or should I answer my question (and give you the credits obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, from the [Command line usage section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html#command-line-usage) of the Python 2 **Idle** documentation it sounded like you could do it in a batch file by starting `idle` and passing it the `-r file` option to get it to run your script. (Note for Python 3, here's the [Command line usage section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#command-line-usage).)

Today I had a chance to explore this further myself and can report that it does indeed appear to work. So now here's what I meant in more concrete terms.

The following batch file is what I used on my Windows 7 (x64) system with the **32**-bit version Python 2.7.14 installed. You will likely have to tweak the file paths used in it to suit your own configuration.

`idletest.bat`

```batch
@echo on
python "C:\Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.py" -r "idletest.py"
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

If Python is in your windows path, one way to interpret / “execute” `myapp.py` in Python via a batch script (.bat) could be :

Starter.bat :

```
@echo off
title “MyApp Launcher”
python2 myapp.py
pause
exit
```

However it does not specifically use the IDLE application !
Also the .bat must be in the same folder (or the path between both elements should be fixed) that `myapp.py` .

NB : Depending on your installation of Python, if it do not work, try replacing `python2` by `python` or by `py`

Comment: As you said, this does not specifically use the IDLE application, therefore it's not what I am looking for.